# MongoDB, PyMongo how to filter results by count of uniques field?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo-3.x

MongoDb contains next set of data

```
[{"user": "a", "domain": "some.com"},
{"user": "b", "domain": "some.com"},
{"user": "b1", "domain": "some.com"},
{"user": "c", "domain": "test.com"},
{"user": "d", "domain": "work.com"},
{"user": "aaa", "domain": "work.com"},
{"user": "some user", "domain": "work.com"} ]
```

I need select first items filtered by domain, no more that 2 same domains in result.
After mongo query result should looks like

```
[{"user": "a", "domain": "some.com"},
{"user": "b", "domain": "some.com"},
{"user": "c", "domain": "test.com"},
{"user": "d", "domain": "work.com"},
{"user": "aaa", "domain": "work.com"}]
```

Just 2 results with same domain,  other with same domains must be skipped. Is this possible do do with $aggregation, $filter or something else?

Is the a way to group by domain and get just first N(2 in example) users data? Example:

```
[{"domain": "some.com", "users": [a, b]}]
```

so

```
{"user": "b1", "domain": "some.com"} will be skip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get desired result performing MongoDB aggregation.

It consists in four stages:
1. We group by `domain` field and accumulate into `data` documents with the same domain name
2. Than, we splice array to set max 2 items per domain
3. We flatten `data` field with `$unwind` operator
4. We return original document structure with `$replaceRoot` operator

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$domain",
      "data": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
     "data": {
        "$slice": [ "$data", 0, 2 ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$data"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: { "newRoot": "$data" }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jwFwE3ArluD) | [Pymongo Aggregation](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/aggregation.html#aggregation-framework)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it's just group results and return unique data, need get first N results based on unique column.  
From this 
[{"user": "a", "domain": "some.com"},
{"user": "b", "domain": "some.com"},
{"user": "b1", "domain": "some.com"}] 

 must get just first 2 

[{"user": "a", "domain": "some.com"},
{"user": "b", "domain": "some.com"}]

Domain just one column that can be used to detect duplicates

Comment: @МаксимДихтярь check again please. I didn't read carefully your specification when I've posted my first answer. Now it`s fine